# PHP PostgreSQL Query Issue

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I have been trying to convert a pg_connect query to PDO as pg_connect give me errors. Below is the query I have that is throwing an error.

```
 <?php
      if (!empty($_GET)) {
        $searchfilters = array( 
          "name"     => "data.name || ' ' || data.lastname ILIKE " . $dbh->quote("%".getvar("name")."%"),
          "room"     => "data.room = " . $dbh->quote(getvar("room")),
          "activity" => "data.activity = " . $dbh->quote(getvar("activity")),
          "date1"    => "data.dob > " . $dbh->quote(getvar("date1")),
          "date2"    => "data.dob < " . $dbh->quote(getvar("date2")),
          "date3"    => "data.joinDate > " . $dbh->quote(getvar("date3")),
          "date4"    => "data.joinDate < " . $dbh->quote(getvar("date4")),
          "date5"    => "data.lastSeen > " . $dbh->quote(getvar("date5")),
          "date6"    => "data.lastSeen < " . $dbh->quote(getvar("date6")),
        );
        $wherequery = array();
        foreach ($searchfilters as $n => $q) {
          $v = getvar($n);
          if (!empty($v)) {
            $wherequery[] = $q;
          }
        }
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT data.id, data.name, lastname, paging, room, activity
                  FROM data";
        if (count($wherequery) > 0) {
          $query .= " WHERE " . (getvar("invert") == "on" ? " NOT " : "") . "(" . implode(" and ", $wherequery) . ")"; 
        }
        $query .= " ORDER BY lastname;";
        $result = pg_query($connection, $query) or 
          die(_("Error in query") . ": $query." . pg_last_error($connection));

        if (pg_num_rows($result) == 0) {
          echo '<div class="alert alert-error">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>
            <h4 class=\"alert-heading\">' . _('No results') . '</h4>
            </div>';
        } else {
          echo '<table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <script language="JavaScript">
                  function toggle(source) {
                    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(\'foo\');
                    for(var i in checkboxes)
                      checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
                  }
                </script>
                <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)"></th>
                <th>' .  _("Name") . '</th>
                <th>' .  _("Activity") . '</th>
                <th>' .  _("Room") . '</th>
                <th>' .  _("Paging") . '</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';
          while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<tr><td style="width:30px"><input type="checkbox" name="foo"></td>';
            echo "<td><a href=\"details.php?id={$row["id"]}\">{$row["name"]} {$row["lastname"]}</a></td>";
            echo '<td>' . $activities[$row["activity"]] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $rooms[$row["room"]] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row["paging"] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
          }
          echo '</tbody></table>';
        }
      }
    ?>
```

The line `$result = pg_query($connection, $query) or 
                  die(_("Error in query") . ": $query." . pg_last_error($connection));` is the part giving me trouble I think.

I futilely tried the following which does not work of course.

```
<?php
  if (!empty($_GET)) {
    $searchfilters = array( 
      "name"     => "data.name || ' ' || data.lastname ILIKE " . $dbh->quote("%".getvar("name")."%"),
      "room"     => "data.room = " . $dbh->quote(getvar("room")),
      "activity" => "data.activity = " . $dbh->quote(getvar("activity")),
      "date1"    => "data.dob > " . $dbh->quote(getvar("date1")),
      "date2"    => "data.dob < " . $dbh->quote(getvar("date2")),
      "date3"    => "data.joinDate > " . $dbh->quote(getvar("date3")),
      "date4"    => "data.joinDate < " . $dbh->quote(getvar("date4")),
      "date5"    => "data.lastSeen > " . $dbh->quote(getvar("date5")),
      "date6"    => "data.lastSeen < " . $dbh->quote(getvar("date6")),
    );
    $wherequery = array();
    foreach ($searchfilters as $n => $q) {
      $v = getvar($n);
      if (!empty($v)) {
        $wherequery[] = $q;
      }
    }
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT data.id, data.name, lastname, paging, room, activity
              FROM data";
    if (count($wherequery) > 0) {
      $query .= " WHERE " . (getvar("invert") == "on" ? " NOT " : "") . "(" . implode(" and ", $wherequery) . ")"; 
    }
    $query .= " ORDER BY lastname;";
    //$result = pg_query($connection, $query) or 
    //  die(_("Error in query") . ": $query." . pg_last_error($connection));

    $sth = $dbh->query('$query');
            while ($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    if (pg_num_rows($result) == 0) {
      echo '<div class="alert alert-error">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>
        <h4 class=\"alert-heading\">' . _('No results') . '</h4>
        </div>';
    } else {
      echo '<table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <script language="JavaScript">
              function toggle(source) {
                checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(\'foo\');
                for(var i in checkboxes)
                  checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
              }
            </script>
            <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)"></th>
            <th>' .  _("Name") . '</th>
            <th>' .  _("Activity") . '</th>
            <th>' .  _("Room") . '</th>
            <th>' .  _("Paging") . '</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';
      while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<tr><td style="width:30px"><input type="checkbox" name="foo"></td>';
        echo "<td><a href=\"details.php?id={$row["id"]}\">{$row["name"]} {$row["lastname"]}</a></td>";
        echo '<td>' . $activities[$row["activity"]] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $rooms[$row["room"]] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row["paging"] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
      }
      echo '</tbody></table>';
    }}
  }
?>
```

Please let me know if you need anything else. I am not very fluent in PHP and am trying to get an open source app running and there are some features that needed some TLC to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Here is the entire page.

The original query was

```
    $sth = $dbh->query('$query');
                              while ($data = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                                echo "<option value=\"{$data[id]}\">
```

And I have tried changing it to:

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- vim: tabstop=2:softtabstop=2 -->
<?php
  require_once "config.php";
  require_once 'functions.php';

  //internationalisation
  $domain = "search";
  require_once 'locale.php';

  function getvar($vname) {
    return array_key_exists($vname, $_POST) ? $_POST[$vname] : $_GET[$vname];
  }

  $dbh = db_connect();

  $connection = pg_connect ("host=$dbhost dbname=$dbname user=$dbuser password=$dbpass");

  $page_title = _("Advanced Search");
  require_once "template/header.php";
?>
          <!-- sidebar -->
          <div class="span3">
            <div class="well sidebar-nav">
              <ul class="nav nav-list">
                <li class="nav-header"><?php echo _("Search") ?></li>
                <li><a href="search.php"><i class="icon-search"></i><?php echo _("Search") ?></a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-filter"></i><?php echo _("Advanced") ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-bookmark"></i><?php echo _("Saved Searches") ?></a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav nav-list">
                <li class="nav-header"><?php echo _("Actions") ?></li>
                <li><a href="register.php"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i><?php echo _("Register") ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i><?php echo _("Register Visitor") ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-print"></i><?php echo _("Print Results") ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-download-alt"></i><?php echo _("Download Results") ?></a></li>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /sidebar -->

          <div class="span9">
            <!-- Search form -->
            <form class="well form-horizontal" method="get">
              <fieldset>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="name"><?php echo _("Name contains") ?></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="input" name="name" id="name" placeholder="<?php echo _("Name") ?>" value="<?php echo getvar("name"); ?>">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="room"><?php echo _("and room is") ?></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <select name="room" id="room">
                      <option value="" selected><?php echo _("Any Room") ?></option>
                        <?php
                          $sth = $dbh->query('SELECT id, name FROM rooms');
                          while ($data = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                            echo "<option value=\"{$data[id]}\">{$data[name]}</option>\n";
                        ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="room"><?php echo _("and class is") ?></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <select name="activity" id="activity">
                      <option value="" selected><?php echo _("Any Class") ?></option>
                      <?php
                        echo (is_null($edata["activity"]) ? "<option disabled selected>" .
                            _("Class") . "</option>\n" : "");
                        $sth = $dbh->query('SELECT id, name FROM activities');
                        while ($data = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                          echo "<option value=\"{$data["id"]}\"" .
                            ($data["id"] == $edata["activity"] ? " selected" : "") .
                            ">{$data["name"]}</option>\n";
                        }
                      ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="medical"><?php echo _("and was born") ?></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <?php echo _("after") ?> <input type="text" class="input-small" name="date1" id="date1" value="<?php echo getvar("date1"); ?>">
                    <?php echo _("and before") ?> <input type="text" class="input-small" name="date2" id="date2" value="<?php echo getvar("date2"); ?>">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="medical"><?php echo _("and joined") ?></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <?php echo _("after") ?> <input type="text" class="input-small" name="date3" id="date3" value="<?php echo getvar("date3"); ?>">
                    <?php echo _("and before") ?> <input type="text" class="input-small" name="date4" id="date4" value="<?php echo getvar("date4"); ?>">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="medical"><?php echo _("and last seen") ?></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <?php echo _("after") ?> <input type="text" class="input-small" name="date5" id="date5" value="<?php echo getvar("date5"); ?>">
                    <?php echo _("and before") ?> <input type="text" class="input-small" name="date6" id="date6" value="<?php echo getvar("date6"); ?>">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="medical"><?php echo _("Invert query") ?></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="invert" id="invert" <?php echo (getvar("invert") == "on" ? "checked" : ""); ?>>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-actions">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="<?php echo _("Search") ?>" />
                  <input type="reset" class="btn" value="<?php echo _("Reset") ?>">
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
            <?php
              if (!empty($_GET)) {
                $searchfilters = array(
                  "name"     => "data.name || ' ' || data.lastname ILIKE " . $dbh->quote("%".getvar("name")."%"),
                  "room"     => "data.room = " . $dbh->quote(getvar("room")),
                  "activity" => "data.activity = " . $dbh->quote(getvar("activity")),
                  "date1"    => "data.dob > " . $dbh->quote(getvar("date1")),
                  "date2"    => "data.dob < " . $dbh->quote(getvar("date2")),
                  "date3"    => "data.joinDate > " . $dbh->quote(getvar("date3")),
                  "date4"    => "data.joinDate < " . $dbh->quote(getvar("date4")),
                  "date5"    => "data.lastSeen > " . $dbh->quote(getvar("date5")),
                  "date6"    => "data.lastSeen < " . $dbh->quote(getvar("date6")),
                );
                $wherequery = array();
                foreach ($searchfilters as $n => $q) {
                  $v = getvar($n);
                  if (!empty($v)) {
                    $wherequery[] = $q;
                  }
                }
                $query = "SELECT DISTINCT  data.id, data.name, data.lastname, data.paging, data.room, data.activity
                          FROM data";
                if (count($wherequery) > 0) {
                  $query .= " WHERE " . (getvar("invert") == "on" ? " NOT " : "") . "(" . implode(" and ", $wherequery) . ")";
                }
                $query .= " ORDER BY data.lastname;";

    //  $sth = $dbh->query('$query');
        //                  while ($data = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        //                    echo "<option value=\"{$data[id]}\">{$data[name]}</option>\n";
        $result = pg_query($connection, $query) or
                die(_("Error in query") . ": $query." . pg_last_error($connection));

                if (pg_num_rows($result) == 0) {
                  echo '<div class="alert alert-error">
                    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>
                    <h4 class=\"alert-heading\">' . _('No results') . '</h4>
                    </div>';
                } else {
                  echo '<table class="table">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <script language="JavaScript">
                          function toggle(source) {
                            checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(\'foo\');
                            for(var i in checkboxes)
                              checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
                          }
                        </script>
                        <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)"></th>
                        <th>' .  _("Name") . '</th>
                        <th>' .  _("Activity") . '</th>
                        <th>' .  _("Room") . '</th>
                        <th>' .  _("Paging") . '</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>';
                  while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo '<tr><td style="width:30px"><input type="checkbox" name="foo"></td>';
                    echo "<td><a href=\"details.php?id={$row["id"]}\">{$row["name"]} {$row["lastname"]}</a></td>";
                    echo '<td>' . $activities[$row["activity"]] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $rooms[$row["room"]] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["paging"] . '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                  }
                  echo '</tbody></table>';
                }
              }
            ?>
          </div>
      </div>
      <script>
        window.onload = function(){
          for(i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
            new JsDatePick({
              useMode:2,
              target:("date" + i),
              dateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d",
              imgPath:"resources/img/datepicker"
            });
          }
        };
      </script>
<?php require_once "template/footer.php" ; ?>
```

Log Results:

```
< 2015-06-21 17:48:10.712 CDT >LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
< 2015-06-21 17:48:10.712 CDT >LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

Conf File:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ERROR REPORTING AND LOGGING
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Where to Log -

log_destination = 'stderr'      # Valid values are combinations of
                    # stderr, csvlog, syslog, and eventlog,
                    # depending on platform.  csvlog
                    # requires logging_collector to be on.

# This is used when logging to stderr:
logging_collector = on          # Enable capturing of stderr and csvlog
                    # into log files. Required to be on for
                    # csvlogs.
                    # (change requires restart)

# These are only used if logging_collector is on:
log_directory = 'pg_log'        # directory where log files are written,
                    # can be absolute or relative to PGDATA
log_filename = 'postgresql-%a.log'  # log file name pattern,
                    # can include strftime() escapes
#log_file_mode = 0600           # creation mode for log files,
                    # begin with 0 to use octal notation
log_truncate_on_rotation = on       # If on, an existing log file with the
                    # same name as the new log file will be
                    # truncated rather than appended to.
                    # But such truncation only occurs on
                    # time-driven rotation, not on restarts
                    # or size-driven rotation.  Default is
                    # off, meaning append to existing files
                    # in all cases.
log_rotation_age = 1d           # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
                    # happen after that time.  0 disables.
log_rotation_size = 0           # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
                    # happen after that much log output.
                    # 0 disables.

# These are relevant when logging to syslog:
#syslog_facility = 'LOCAL0'
#syslog_ident = 'postgres'

# This is only relevant when logging to eventlog (win32):
#event_source = 'PostgreSQL'

# - When to Log -

client_min_messages = notice        # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   log
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error

log_min_messages = error        # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   info
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error
                    #   log
                    #   fatal
                    #   panic

log_min_error_statement = error # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   info
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error
                    #   log
                    #   fatal
                    #   panic (effectively off)

#log_min_duration_statement = -1    # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements
                    # and their durations, > 0 logs only
                    # statements running at least this number
                    # of milliseconds


# - What to Log -

#debug_print_parse = off
#debug_print_rewritten = off
#debug_print_plan = off
#debug_pretty_print = on
#log_checkpoints = off
#log_connections = off
#log_disconnections = off
#log_duration = off
log_error_verbosity = default       # terse, default, or verbose messages
#log_hostname = off
log_line_prefix = '< %m >'          # special values:
                    #   %a = application name
                    #   %u = user name
                    #   %d = database name
                    #   %r = remote host and port
                    #   %h = remote host
                    #   %p = process ID
                    #   %t = timestamp without milliseconds
                    #   %m = timestamp with milliseconds
                    #   %i = command tag
                    #   %e = SQL state
                    #   %c = session ID
                    #   %l = session line number
                    #   %s = session start timestamp
                    #   %v = virtual transaction ID
                    #   %x = transaction ID (0 if none)
                    #   %q = stop here in non-session
                    #        processes
                    #   %% = '%'
                    # e.g. '<%u%%%d> '
#log_lock_waits = off           # log lock waits >= deadlock_timeout
#log_statement = 'none'         # none, ddl, mod, all
#log_temp_files = -1            # log temporary files equal or larger
                    # than the specified size in kilobytes;
                    # -1 disables, 0 logs all temp files
log_timezone = 'America/Indiana/Tell_City'


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RUNTIME STATISTICS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Query/Index Statistics Collector -

#track_activities = on
#track_counts = on
#track_io_timing = off
#track_functions = none         # none, pl, all
#track_activity_query_size = 1024   # (change requires restart)
#update_process_title = on
#stats_temp_directory = 'pg_stat_tmp'


# - Statistics Monitoring -

#log_parser_stats = off
#log_planner_stats = off
#log_executor_stats = off
#log_statement_stats = off


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# AUTOVACUUM PARAMETERS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#autovacuum = on            # Enable autovacuum subprocess?  'on'
                    # requires track_counts to also be on.
#log_autovacuum_min_duration = -1   # -1 disables, 0 logs all actions and
                    # their durations, > 0 logs only
                    # actions running at least this number
                    # of milliseconds.
#autovacuum_max_workers = 3     # max number of autovacuum subprocesses
                    # (change requires restart)
#autovacuum_naptime = 1min      # time between autovacuum runs
#autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 50   # min number of row updates before
                    # vacuum
#autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 50  # min number of row updates before
                    # analyze
#autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.2   # fraction of table size before vacuum
#autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.1  # fraction of table size before analyze
#autovacuum_freeze_max_age = 200000000  # maximum XID age before forced vacuum
                    # (change requires restart)
#autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age = 400000000    # maximum Multixact age
                    # before forced vacuum
                    # (change requires restart)
#autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 20ms    # default vacuum cost delay for
                    # autovacuum, in milliseconds;
                    # -1 means use vacuum_cost_delay
#autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = -1  # default vacuum cost limit for
                    # autovacuum, -1 means use
                    # vacuum_cost_limit


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CLIENT CONNECTION DEFAULTS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Statement Behavior -

#search_path = '"$user",public'     # schema names
#default_tablespace = ''        # a tablespace name, '' uses the default
#temp_tablespaces = ''          # a list of tablespace names, '' uses
                    # only default tablespace
#check_function_bodies = on
#default_transaction_isolation = 'read committed'
#default_transaction_read_only = off
#default_transaction_deferrable = off
#session_replication_role = 'origin'
#statement_timeout = 0          # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled
#lock_timeout = 0           # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled
#vacuum_freeze_min_age = 50000000
#vacuum_freeze_table_age = 150000000
#vacuum_multixact_freeze_min_age = 5000000
#vacuum_multixact_freeze_table_age = 150000000
#bytea_output = 'hex'           # hex, escape
#xmlbinary = 'base64'
#xmloption = 'content'

# - Locale and Formatting -

datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
#intervalstyle = 'postgres'
timezone = 'America/Indiana/Tell_City'
#timezone_abbreviations = 'Default'     # Select the set of available time zone
                    # abbreviations.  Currently, there are
                    #   Default
                    #   Australia (historical usage)
                    #   India
                    # You can create your own file in
                    # share/timezonesets/.
#extra_float_digits = 0         # min -15, max 3
#client_encoding = sql_ascii        # actually, defaults to database
                    # encoding

# These settings are initialized by initdb, but they can be changed.
lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'         # locale for system error message
                    # strings
lc_monetary = 'en_US.UTF-8'         # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'en_US.UTF-8'          # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'en_US.UTF-8'             # locale for time formatting

# default configuration for text search
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'

# - Other Defaults -

#dynamic_library_path = '$libdir'
#local_preload_libraries = ''


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# LOCK MANAGEMENT
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#deadlock_timeout = 1s
#max_locks_per_transaction = 64     # min 10
                    # (change requires restart)
# Note:  Each lock table slot uses ~270 bytes of shared memory, and there are
# max_locks_per_transaction * (max_connections + max_prepared_transactions)
# lock table slots.
#max_pred_locks_per_transaction = 64    # min 10
                    # (change requires restart)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# VERSION/PLATFORM COMPATIBILITY
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Previous PostgreSQL Versions -

#array_nulls = on
#backslash_quote = safe_encoding    # on, off, or safe_encoding
#default_with_oids = off
#escape_string_warning = on
#lo_compat_privileges = off
#quote_all_identifiers = off
#sql_inheritance = on
#standard_conforming_strings = on
#synchronize_seqscans = on

# - Other Platforms and Clients -

#transform_null_equals = off


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ERROR HANDLING
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#exit_on_error = off            # terminate session on any error?
#restart_after_crash = on       # reinitialize after backend crash?


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONFIG FILE INCLUDES
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# These options allow settings to be loaded from files other than the
# default postgresql.conf.

#include_dir = 'conf.d'         # include files ending in '.conf' from
                    # directory 'conf.d'
#include_if_exists = 'exists.conf'  # include file only if it exists
#include = 'special.conf'       # include file


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CUSTOMIZED OPTIONS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Add settings for extensions here
```

Comment: Can you post the error that its throwing?

Comment: including the executed query preferably.

Comment: `$dbh->query('$query')`: why quotes? Besides, variables are not substitued by their value with single quotes. Also, you can't mix pg_\* functions with PDO ones: they don't share their connections so they are mutually incompatible (replace them all to their PDO equivalent: pg_num_rows => PDOStatement::rowCount, pg_fetch_assoc => PDOStatement::fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)). I also guess, the first while is at the wrong place.

Comment: I added the entire page if that helps. Please let me know if this is clear or not?

Comment: @scrowler The error is just Error in query: SELECT DISTINCT data.id, data.name, data.lastname, data.paging, data.room, data.activity FROM data ORDER BY data.lastname;. but I can run the query manually and get results.

Comment: "Error in query:" isn't a PostgreSQL error message, please post the real error message. Use pg_result_error(), pg_result_error_field(), pg_result_status() and pg_connection_status() for better error handling, not pg_last_error.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, I am not super fluent in postgre or php, I replaced ph_last_error and none of those actually print any errors.  See my edit above for the log conf as well as the lack of results.